# How to migrate from Joomla to WordPress on same server through cpanel

Tags: database, wordpress, joomla, migration, cpanel

I am fairly new to programming, I would like to know if anyone can help me(step-by-step) how to migrate from joomla to wordpress on the same server through cpanel. Any advice or link to a website that have the guide is very appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout this WordPress plugin:
https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/fg-joomla-to-wordpress/